# Inheritance caching patterns in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

Say I have a parent class:

```
class Stat

  def val
    raise "method must be implemented by subclass"
  end

end
```

And a subclass:

```
class MyStat < Stat

  def val
    #performs costly calculation and returns value
  end    

end
```

By virtue of extending the parent class, I would like the subclass to not have to worry about caching the return value of the "val" method.

There are many patterns one could employ here to this effect, and I've tried several on for size, but none of them feel right to me and I know this is a solved problem so it feels silly to waste the time and effort. How is this most commonly dealt with?

Also, it's occurred to me that I may be asking the wrong questions. Maybe I should't be using inheritance at all but composition instead.

Any and all thoughts appreciated.

Edit:

Solution I went with can be summed up as follows:

```
class Stat

  def value
    @value ||= build_value 
  end

  def build_value
    #to be implemented by subclass
  end

end
```

Comment: Abstract base classes are not something you often see in Ruby, there's no standard way of declaring them and stubbing in a `raise` is a pretty desperate move by Ruby standards. Normally you'll see the base class implement the null case, or do the least possible work, with documentation making it clear your subclass has to implement a number of things. Having tests to exercise all the methods is critical, there's no leaning on the compiler here to catch mistakes. Coach people on what they should do. Don't raise a fuss if they didn't listen.

Comment: @tadman thanks that's good to hear. My first language was java and I can't help but feel it holds pernicious sway over my design related thinking in other languages. The ruby way is to fail quietly. I just can't help but feel that code should be self-documenting, and so the thought that the code I write might not make sense without some lengthy documentation I've written for it is troubling to me, though maybe it shouldn't be.

Comment: Just like how people learning one language carry an accent from another, the same holds true when programming. The Java way and the Ruby way are often at odds, where Ruby is far more casual. As such testing is the only way to validate that the correct behaviour has been implemented. Abstract base classes are just one way to solve the problem, but there are other ways to the same objective. Personally I like  meagar's answer, it's the Ruby way with a small concession to your exception requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically I use a simple pattern regardless of the presence of inheritance:

```
class Parent
  def val
    @val ||= calculate_val
  end

  def calculate_value
    fail "Implementation missing"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def calculate_val
    # some expensive computation
  end
end
```

I always prefer to wrap the complex and expensive logic in its own method  or methods that have no idea that their return value will be [memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). It gives you a cleaner separation of concerns; one method is for caching, one method is for computing.

It also happens to give you a nice way of overriding the logic, without overriding the caching logic.

In the simple example above, the memoized method `val` is pretty redundant. But the pattern it also lets you memoize methods that accept arguments, or when the actual caching is less trivial, maintaining that separation of responsibilities between caching and computing:

```
def is_prime(n)
  @is_prime ||= {}
  @is_prime[n] ||= compute_is_prime
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually had this written at one point, but unfortunately I also want to cache the value of a method "to_string" as well and I don't like the sound of "calculate_string". I could say "calculate_value" and "build_string" but then I'd be using different language to describe the same type of method. I think I will probably end up using "build_" everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the method names same and not create new methods to put logic in, then prepend modules instead of using parent/child inheritance.

```
module MA
  def val
    puts("module's method")
    @_val ||= super
  end
end

class CA
  def val
    puts("class's method")
    1
  end

  prepend MA
end

ca = CA.new
ca.val # will print "module's method" and "class's method". will return 1.
ca.val # will print "module's method". will return 1.
```

Comment: This is beautiful. It seems `prepend` has several useful usages.

Comment: This is pretty great, unfortunately I didn't fully articulate my use case and it turns out this won't work for me. I have a whole inheritance hierarchy several levels deep (StatUnit is the parent class, Stat and StatSet inherit from StatUnit, and Stat and StatSet have children with their own children, etc.) and if I implement this in my top level class it doesn't work with any of that class's children.

Comment: In that situation, I would go with what @meager, has responded with. Please note though that I would discourage your Java-type implementation of abstract classes in Ruby. I'm obviously assuming that `Stat` (the top-most parent) is an abstract class and it isn't being instantiated anywhere. If this is the case, then the more Ruby-like approach would be to turn `Stat` into a module (perhaps `StatMethods`) and include it in the classes (or parent-classes) that are actually being instantiated.